# how to read mail from Google mail and mark as save and save mail in local folder with C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, email

I am trying to build a winform app to

1. read mails from google app
2. save mail and attachment to local folder
3. mark mail as read
4. Save the email body and attachments to a SQL-Server database

The latter is ok but I'm really having trouble with the first 3.
I've look everywhere and people are telling me how to send mail on a winform app but not how to read, mark and save content and attachment.

Comment: I assume your best bet would be IMAP. You can find a number of freely-available libraries.

Comment: Have you tried the gmail atom feed ? For ex: query to: http://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/unread/

Comment: There are two standardized protocols for reading email, [POP3 (SO)](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+pop3) and [IMAP (SO)](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+imap).  They both can fulfill your 1-3 requirements, but neither are built in into c# by default.  However your question is extremely broad (enough to be closed) so there most likely won't be a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

CodeProject is probably the next best resource online after SO (IMHO.) Here are some well-reviewed sample projects that will get you a long way:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14304/POP3-Email-Client-NET-2-0
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6062/A-POP3-Client-in-C-NET
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188349/Read-Gmail-Inbox-Message-in-ASP-NET
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34495/Building-your-own-Mail-Client-using-C
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15611/POP3-Email-Client-with-full-MIME-Support-NET-2-0